# Why is my && statement not working in this fighting game I made?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have spent the last 3 hours trying to make this code work. If your HP is at zero, I want an alert to pop up saying "You lose!" If the enemy's HP is zero, alert should say "You win!". If both are at zero, then it should say "It's a draw!".

I've messed around with trying to make the ifs into "!" and have probably switched the order of the if's  like 50 times. I once had it completely correct, but that was when I had HP starting at 10 and the random only *3. Once I updated to 100 and *50, the draw started to not work again.

If anyone can help, that would be amazing!!

```
let yourHp = 100;
let enemyHp = 100;

function attack() {
    let attack = 100;
    //Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
    let enemyAttack = 50;
    //Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);

    if (!(enemyHp <= 0)) {
        //how much you attack for
        enemyHp -= attack;

        //setting enemy Hp minus how much your attack was
        enemyHpp(enemyHp);

        //setting how much you attacked for
        damage(attack);

        //If both you and the enemy are at 0, it's a draw
    }
    if (!enemyHp >= 0 && !yourHp > 0) {
        enemyHp = 0;
        yourHp = 0;
        enemyHpp(enemyHp);
        yourHpp(yourHp);
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert("It's a draw!");
        }, 1);
        document.location.reload();
    } else if (!(enemyHp >= 0)) {
        //If enemy is at 0, you win
        enemyHp = 0;
        enemyHpp(enemyHp);
        yourHpp(yourHp);
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert('You win!');
        }, 1);
        document.location.reload();
    }

    //how much enemy attacks for
    yourHp -= enemyAttack;

    //setting your Hp minus how much enemy attack was
    yourHpp(yourHp);

    //setting how much enemy attacked for
    enemyDamage(enemyAttack);

    if (!(yourHp >= 0)) {
        //If only you are at 0, you lose
        yourHp = 0;
        yourHpp(yourHp);
        enemyHpp(enemyHp);
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert('You lose!');
        }, 1);
        document.location.reload();
    }
}

//Making the outputs show in the body
function damage(msg) {
    document.getElementById('damage').innerHTML = msg;
}

function enemyHpp(msg) {
    document.getElementById('enemyHp').innerHTML = msg;
}

function enemyDamage(msg) {
    document.getElementById('enemyDamage').innerHTML = msg;
}

function yourHpp(msg) {
    document.getElementById('yourHp').innerHTML = msg;
}
```

I switched the code to the following per the answer and the code still shows a draw as "me" winning...

```
if (enemyHp <= 0 && yourHp <= 0) {
        enemyHp = 0;
        yourHp = 0;
        enemyHpp(enemyHp);
        yourHpp(yourHp);
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert("It's a draw!");
        }, 1);
        document.location.reload();
    } else if (enemyHp <= 0) {
        //If enemy is at 0, you win
        enemyHp = 0;
        enemyHpp(enemyHp);
        yourHpp(yourHp);
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert('You win!');
        }, 1);
        document.location.reload();
    } else if (yourHp <= 0) {
        //If only you are at 0, you lose
        yourHp = 0;
        yourHpp(yourHp);
        enemyHpp(enemyHp);
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert('You lose!');
        }, 1);
        document.location.reload();
    }
```

Comment: put a console.log within the 'you win' block to see what the actual variable values are in there when you end up winning when you think it should be a draw.  Even better than console.logs are breakpoints.  Here is a link to a document showing how to do that: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints

Comment: You are the best! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the breakpoint in Chrome (thank you for the sugestion KaeyangTheG!!), it really helped. Working code as follows:

```
let yourHp = 100;
let enemyHp = 100;

function attack() {
    let attack = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
    let enemyAttack = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);

    if (enemyHp >= 0) {
        //how much you attack for
        enemyHp -= attack;

        //setting enemy Hp minus how much your attack was
        enemyHpp(enemyHp);

        //setting how much you attacked for
        damage(attack);

        //If both you and the enemy are at 0, it's a draw
    }
    //how much enemy attacks for
    yourHp -= enemyAttack;

    //setting your Hp minus how much enemy attack was
    yourHpp(yourHp);

    //setting how much enemy attacked for
    enemyDamage(enemyAttack);

    if (enemyHp <= 0 && yourHp <= 0) {
        enemyHp = 0;
        yourHp = 0;
        enemyHpp(enemyHp);
        yourHpp(yourHp);
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert("It's a draw!");
        }, 1);
        document.location.reload();
    } else if (enemyHp <= 0) {
        //If enemy is at 0, you win
        enemyHp = 0;
        console.log(enemyHp);
        console.log(yourHp);
        enemyHpp(enemyHp);
        yourHpp(yourHp);
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert('You win!');
        }, 1);
        document.location.reload();
    } else if (yourHp <= 0) {
        //If only you are at 0, you lose
        yourHp = 0;
        yourHpp(yourHp);
        enemyHpp(enemyHp);
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert('You lose!');
        }, 1);
        document.location.reload();
    }
}

//Making the outputs show in the body
function damage(msg) {
    document.getElementById('damage').innerHTML = msg;
}

function enemyHpp(msg) {
    document.getElementById('enemyHp').innerHTML = msg;
}

function enemyDamage(msg) {
    document.getElementById('enemyDamage').innerHTML = msg;
}

function yourHpp(msg) {
    document.getElementById('yourHp').innerHTML = msg;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This statement:

```
if (!enemyHp >= 0 && !yourHp > 0) {
```

needs more parentheses to do what you want. As it is, it means:

```
if ((!enemyHp) >= 0 && (!yourHp) >= 0))
```

Which doesn't seem to match what you describe the intended behaviour is.

You probably want:

```
if ((enemyHp <= 0) && (yourHp <= 0)) {
     // draw
} else if (enemyHp <= 0) {
     // win
} else if (yourHp <= 0) {
     // lose
}
```

Comment: I switched to that and a draw still shows that you win